# What are some examples of known $0$-th homotopy groups?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I understand that $\pi_0(X)$ is the pointed set of path components of $X$, but what are some examples?

If $F$ is the fibre of some fibration then $\pi_0(F)$ is isomorphic to F as a pointed set. What about $\mathbb{R}P^n, S^1\times S^1, S^\infty, $ or other CW Complexes?

Comment: Those spaces you listed are all path connected, so $\pi_0$ is a singleton. I don't think I understand your statement about the fibre of a fibration, since $S^1$ is the fibre of many fibrations but $\pi_0(S^1)= 0\neq S^1$. However, if $X$ is a discrete space then indeed $\pi_0(X) \cong X$.

Comment: An interesting example that is NOT a CW complex is the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve). This space is connected but not path-connected, in particular $\pi_0$ has two elements.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is another example of a space where $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Q}$, even though it is not discrete. (You can see this with a proof by contradiction using the intermediate value theorem.)

Comment: @William so is the cardinality of $\pi_0$ just the number of path components? If a space X had two path components, how would you write $\pi_0(X)$?

Comment: @William I meant to say $F$ is a discrete fibre. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: $\pi_0X$ is not a group in general.

Comment: Yes, $|\pi_0(X)|$ is the number of path components. More explicitly there is a canonical map $X \to \pi_0(X)$ sending a point $x\in X$ to the homotopy class of the function $f_x \colon S^0 \to X$ where $f_x(1) = x_0$ (the basepoint) and $f_x(-1) = x$; this map $X \to \pi_0(X)$ induces a bijection between the set of path components and $\pi_0(X)$. The key idea is that a *pointed* homotopy $S^0\times I \to X$ is equivalent to an un-pointed homotopy $\{-1\}\times I \to X$, which is just a path.

Comment: If $\pi_0(X)$ has two elements, you could always write something like $\pi_0(X) \cong \{[x], [y]\}$ where $x$ and $y$ are in different path components. Saying something like $\pi_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ has the potential to be misleading, because as Tyrone points out it is not a group in general. (If $G$ is a topological group then the continuous group structure does induce a group structure on $\pi_0(G)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $(X, x_0)$ is a pointed space, let $C$ be the set of path components of $X$, and recall $\pi_0(X)$ is the set of pointed-homotopy classes of pointed functions $S^0\to X$ (where $1$ is the basepoint of $S^0$).

For each $x\in X$, define $f_x\colon S^0 \to X$ by $f_x(1) = x_0$ and $f_x(-1) = x$. Observe that $x$ and $y$ are in the same path component if and only if $f_x$ is homotopic to $f_y$, so the relation defining $C$ is in this sense equivalent to the relation defining $\pi_0(X)$. In fact

> The function $\Phi\colon X\to \pi_0(X)$ sending $x$ to $f_x$ induces a bijection $C \cong \pi_0(X)$. In other words, $\pi_0(X)$ is naturally identified with the set of path components of $X$.

You should work out all the details for yourself as an exercise, to help your understanding of $\pi_0$.

---

**Examples**

1. The three spaces you gave, $\mathbb{RP}^n$, $S^1\times S^1$, and $S^\infty$, are all path-connected so $\pi_0$ is trivial. (In fact $S^\infty$ is contractible.)
2. Be careful not to confuse "connected" with "path-connected", as "path-connected" is strictly stronger. Every path-connected space is connected, because the unit interval is connected. If a space is connected and *locally* path-connected (such as a connected CW complex or manifold) then it is path-connected; however, there are connected spaces which are *not* path-connected, such as the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) where $\pi_0$ has two elements.
3. If $X$ is discrete then each point is a path component, so $\Phi\colon X\to \pi_0(X)$ is already a bijection. More generally, $\Phi$ will be a bijection if $X$ is [totally disconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space) (this follows from the fact that the unit interval is connected), so for example $\pi_0(\mathbb{Q})\cong \mathbb{Q}$ even though $\mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete.
4. If $F$ is the fibre of some fibration $p\colon E \to B$ then $\pi_0(F)$ fits into the [long exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration#Long_exact_sequence_of_homotopy_groups) $$ \dots \to \pi_1(F) \to  \pi_1(E) \to \pi_1(B) \to \pi_0(F) \to \pi_0(E)$$ (where "exactness" for $\pi_0$ is in the sense of pointed sets, because they are not generally groups). In the particular case that $E\to B$ is a connected covering space (so the fibres are discrete) in particular this implies $F \cong \pi_1(B) /p_*(\pi_1(E))$ as pointed sets.
5. If $G$ is a topological group then $\pi_0(G)$ inherits a group structure (exercise: confirm this). If $G_0\subset G$ denotes the path component of the identity then $G_0$ is a subgroup (hint: multiply paths together) and there is a short exact sequence $G_0 \to G \to \pi_0(G)$; in particular $G_0$ is a normal subgroup.
6. The [Mapping Class Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group) of a smooth manifold $M$ (as in JCAA's answer) is defined by taking the infinite-dimensional Lie group of diffeomorphisms $\text{Diff}(M)$ modulo isotopy. If you think about the definitions you'll see that an isotopy of diffeomorphisms is nothing more than a path through the space of diffeomorphisms, and so the mapping class group is precisely $\pi_0(\text{Diff}(M))$. By the previous paragraph, this is equivalent to $\text{Diff}(M) / \text{Diff}(M)_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping class group of a surface (or, more generally, any manifold) $M$ is $\pi_0(\mathrm{Diff}(M))$.

Comment: What is "Diff" ?

Comment: The diffeomorphism group of the manifold (sometimes restricted to diffs preserving the orientation, if the manifold is oriented).

Comment: @William: You are right. I have restored my original answer.

Comment: It is also sometimes defined as the quotient $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$ by the group of diffeomorphisms that are homotopic to the identity.

Comment: For a topological group $G$ the identity component $G_0$ is a normal subgroup and in fact $\pi_0(G) \cong G / G_0$, so these two definitions of the mapping class group are indeed equivalent.